Grid DB Connection Issue using gss-client
I have installed the Grid DB server on my RHEL machine and further I am trying to connect to the GridDB server. From the online docs, I see that there are two different downloads - Server & Connector.

My query is can I use gss-client to connect to the Grid DB server ?
If so, how to connect ?
I don't see on CLI client on their Downloads (connector) page and need to confirm the same here.
[+] https://griddb.net/en/downloads/

I couldn't find much details about it on official docs.
https://www.griddb.net/en/docs/GridDB_OperationGuide.html#sec-1
I tried downloading the GridDB server and successfully installed it. Now, I am trying to connect to the server to test the performance of my GridDB and to experiment more with it.
I am stuck at connection part and need expert opinion as to where I am wrong or what can be further steps.
Tried as below --
$$ gss-client -user admin -pass admin
Usage: gss-client [-port port] [-mech mechanism] [-spnego] [-d]
       [-seq] [-noreplay] [-nomutual] [-user user] [-pass pw]
       [-f] [-q] [-ccount count] [-mcount count]
       [-v1] [-na] [-nw] [-nx] [-nm] host service msg

